# Relationship between testosterone and muscle growth

Tags: strength, muscle, workout, sports, testosterone

Today I did a testosterone test and the result was **25.77 nmol/L** (normal range **9.9 - 27.8**). Can somebody tell me what this means in terms of muscle growth? (age almost 30)

Comment: I would expect that your answer is going to be dependent upon many different individual qualities.  Seems like something you could research on your own, or, speak to a physician about.

Answer (score 2):

While increasing testosterone levels above natural levels with the use of  steroids can help add appreciable mass, increasing T levels within the natural range does not seem to have the same effect. 
[Endocrinology. 2006 Jan;147(1):141-54. Epub 2005 Oct 6.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16210377)

In short, being close to the top of the range will not make you a effortless star athlete. You must still work hard like everyone else

Comment: Damn son, for a second I thought that I am genetically gifted :)) nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really.

Having a healty testosterone level means only you dont have any disorder in your Hypotalamic-Pituitary-Gonadal Axis.

When you perform a workout you have a transient increase in in the levels of some of your hormones: testosterone is one of them.

It regulates the homeodynamic state of muscle by some signaling patterns involving certain molecular actors ( Akt-mTORC1 ).

Women are also capable of increasing muscle mass, even with their pratically non existent level of testosterone. The basal levels of this hormone are not a good predictor of ones potential to grow mass-wise, but they only influence the actual initial level of fat free mass ( and obviously other variables related to sex differences ).

Comment: But if testosterone doesn't have nothing with muscle growth,why do women grow harder than men?